# Quantum gate count minimization

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, circuit-construction

In classical digital logic, we have K-map and Quine–McCluskey algorithm for minimizing boolean equation, thereby reducing the number of logic gates needed. Is there such a thing in quantum computing?.

One of the exercises from IBM Quantum Summer School 2022 is to achieve this quantum state

[image]

and this is my solution (which passed grader check)

[image]

The question is: in general, how do I know that a derived circuit is optimal/state of the art?

Comment: It's a difficult thing, for quantum, I know we have [Solovay-Kitaev algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030) and also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04743) with the machine learning method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know if there is a systematic way to find out whether a circuit is optimal or not.
But to that specific simple problem you could have used also one of the following 2 options:

[image]

q0 - Your solution.
q1 + q2 - Other, shorter possible solutions.

This photo is from IBM Quantum Composer - you can see on the right side that all 3 options result in the same state.

Comment: Try to run the circuit on real QPU and have a look at the job. There you will see both your original circuit and transpiled one. The latter is composed of QPU native gates. I suspect that you will see almost same gates on all three qubits.

Comment: q0 + q1 are indeed the same in the transpiled version (and consisted of 2 gates). q2 is the most efficient one consisted only of 1 gate [sqrt(X) is a native gate and it does exactly pi/2 rotation around the x-axis]